# How to return getVisibleValues() with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering

Do you know why the `getVisibleValues()` function doesn't return any values? I would like to get a filtering criterion, for example in this case (screenshot) I'd like to get the 'A' value. I tried `getCriteriaValues()` , `getValues()`and it doesn't work too. It doesn't not return any values. Only the `getHiddenValues()` function works and returns "B, C, D" correctly.

[image: screenshot]

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test1');
var filter = sheet.getRange('A1:C').getFilter();
  var values = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(3).getVisibleValues();
  
  Logger.log(values);
  
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFilter' of null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. You can report in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B).

#### This method is not currently supported:

See issue [159051708](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159051708):

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior) Hello,
>
> Unfortunately those methods are not currently supported. As you try to
> use them in your script you will see an Exception message:
>
> Visible values are not currently supported. As an alternative specify
> a list of hidden values that excludes the values that should be
> visible.
>
> Hidden values are supported.

You could create a separate function to simulate this:

```
function test_getVisibleValues() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test1");
  const columnRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C");
  const filter = columnRange.getFilter();
  const visibleValues = getVisibleValues(filter, columnRange);
  console.log(visibleValues);
}

/**
 * Returns the values to show.
 * Simulates https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria#getvisiblevalues
 * @param {Filter} filter
 * @param {Range} range
 * @returns {string[]}
 */
function getVisibleValues(filter, range) {
  const filterCriteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(range.getColumn());
  const hiddenValues = filterCriteria.getHiddenValues();
  const allNonBlankValues = range.getValues().filter(String);
  const uniqueValues = Array.from(new Set(allNonBlankValues));
      
  // filter unique values that aren't hidden
  return uniqueValues.flat().filter(value => !hiddenValues.includes(value));
}
```

Comment: In fact, i found info by support, that these functions are not supported :(

Answer (score 2):

I thought to do it this way:

- Get all the values ​​first.
- Then filter out the empty and not unique.
- And then filter out hidden values ​​from them.

Do you know how to do it?

```html
function getcriteria() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test1")
var range = sheet.getRange('C2:C');

//get hidden values
var filter = range.getFilter();
var hiddenValues = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(3).getHiddenValues();

//get all values, filter blank
var all = range.getValues().filter(String);

//filter unique 
var allUnique = 

//filter allUnique - hiddenValues
var filtered = 
      }
```

Comment: I updated my answer with my approach to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getFilterValues(filter, range) {
  const filterCriteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(range.getColumn());
  const hiddenValues = filterCriteria.getHiddenValues();
  const allValues = range.getValues().slice(1).flat().map(value => value.toString());
  const uniqueValues = Array.from(new Set(allValues));  
  var visibleValues = uniqueValues.filter(value => !hiddenValues.includes(value));
  return {
    'visibleValues':visibleValues,
    'hiddenValues':hiddenValues,
    'uniqueValues':uniqueValues
  }
}
```